# Expectation of an exponential bivariate case E(exp(abXY))

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am trying to solve  $\mathbb E[\exp(abXY)]$ where $a$ and $b$ are parameters, and $X$, $Y$ are zero-mean Gaussian random variables with variance $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ respectively. I suppose that they are independent.

For example, for the univariate case we have:

$$\mathbb E[\exp(a b X)] = \exp (a^2 b^2 \sigma_x^2 / 2),$$

from the [Bolton contract theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0dYD.jpg), but I want some similar expression for the bivariate case, How can I solve that?

Comment: Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers I don't think the expectation is finite unless $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Complete the square in the x integral and use the fact it is a normal distribution then complete the square in the y integral

Comment: i don't arribe anything